# How can I go about making this code only show the div tag when the user scrolls to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below currently moves the div tag 'navigation' (a header) to the top of the page on scroll down, and moves it back down (underneath a second header) when you scroll up. I'm trying to adjust it so that it doesn't move back down every scroll up, but when you reach the top of the page. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

```
// Move header on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.navigation').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.navigation').removeClass('.navigation').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.navigation').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('.navigation');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: `setInterval`... are you actively polling for scroll? Why?

Comment: Is there something wrong with that? What should I do it improve?

Comment: Use event handlers, which you are _already doing_ with `$(window).scroll`.

Comment: `$(window).on('scroll', function(){});`. Also I believe that `$(this).scrollTop();` - is undefined, delta is null

Comment: Since I can't answer my own question because I have less than 10 reputation, I'll answer it here.
  
Welp, I came to my senses and reflected upon a different script I made for something similar, examined my code and realized that all I needed to do was remove everything in my scroll up if statement and replace it with st < 100. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) { 
      // position menu for when unscrolled
   }
   else {
     // position menu for when scrolled
   }
});
```

Here is an application similar to what you are trying to do to illustrate the function: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/R9qLN/2/)

Comment: Can also do a range of approach with `if($(window).scrollTop() <= 15)` so as they approach the top it shows.

Comment: @WASasquatch, very true... especially if it is paired with a `fadeIn()`, `slideDown()` or `animate({css})` effect it would look nice for the menu to start animating in before the top is reached

Comment: Definitely make it look more appealing and "intelligent" looking.